# Modeling an embedded system hardware using UML

Tags: deployment, embedded, uml, modeling

I am trying to draw a Deployment Model for a simple embedded system that basically consists of six hardware parts (MCU, keypad, LCD, stepper motor, relay, lamp). Since the Deployment Model helps to show how the hardware is connected, I decided to represent these hardware parts as Nodes. So in my case all the parts are connected to the MCU inside a node, named ControlBoard, with a stereotype `<<device>>`. Is this an accepted approach? and why?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your diagram is correct. But, set device stereotype to all nodes. if there is not this stereotype, node is common  node without knowledge if it is device or execution environment.
Good source to learn how to create your model is UML Superstructure part deployment. [UML Website](http://www.uml.org)